# Визуально соединить (склеить) два div

Tags: css

Все испробовала, не могу найти подходящие коды.

```css
.parent {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: flex;
 margin: auto;          
    
}

.block {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
 margin: auto;
}

.block2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: а что значит соединить ?

Answer (score 2):

Я правильно понял, что нужен такой результат?

```css
.parent {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: flex;
 align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    
}

.block {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.block2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее!!!!